# Using WCF web service from monodroid application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, xamarin

I'm trying to test my WCF web service from an Android application but I get this error:

```
No overload for method 'GetData' takes 1 arguments
```

This is the code:

```
        using client01.TestService;

        EditText = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.EditText);
        TestService.Service TS = new TestService.Service();
        EditText.Text = TS.GetData(7);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the definition of TS.GetData() to see how many parameters the function takes.

Comment: it gets one parameter : string GetData(int value);

Can you please help me to understand this line: 
TestService.Service TS = new TestService.Service();

what is TestService? and TestService.service?